# How to find (Bosch Disto GLM 50 C) Bluetooth List Command for Android/Python

Tags: python, android, bluetooth

I have a project connecting the Bosch GML 50C to android devices using bluetooth.

Problems

- I want to change the measurement types from Android.
- I also need to receive the data from the bluetooth device each time it calculate the distance.

Please help if you could know how to list all the command hex code for this devices. For example: C04000EE  sending request data measurement from android to Bosch GML 50C. Thank you!

There are few commands i found from the forum but not enough https://www.eevblog.com/forum/projects/hacking-the-bosch-glm-20-laser-measuring-tape/

This app can change the setting mesurement and receive data when calculate from the BOSCH devices
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bosch.measuringmaster